# Displaying attribute value from related layer in QGIS Atlas?

Tags: qgis, atlas, relates

I work on QGIS 3.4.4 Madeira. I have two related layers in my project :"towns" (polygon) and "interest points" (points), the common field is "town name".

In the Atlas, my cover layer is "towns".

I would like to put labels wich display values from different fields of the child layer ("interest points") corresponding to the current entity of the Atlas. It seems easy but I can't find the correct expression.

---

My cover layer in the Atlas is "towns" and in each town, I have several "interest points". The layer "interest points" have many fields and I would like to insert data from a given field of the child layer using an expression in the labelling (text) tool and not the table tool. So I need an expression to insert the value inside a sentence for example.

I tried relation-aggregate function, it returns values from child layer but it necessarily "calculates" (min, max, sum…). And I only want to display the child related value.

Comment: How do u want to aggregate the attributes of your child layer 'interest points' in case there are several points in your 'town' ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "corresponding to the current entity of the atlas." If you mean points that intersect the current atlas feature, here's an answer:

Use Rule-Based Labeling for the point layer. Create a rule with this filter expression:

```
 within( $geometry , @atlas_feature )
```

Select the field that you want to label the point with.

You can create a separate rule for each field, or combine multiple fields into a single label. Use an expression such as this:

```
concat( "field1", '; ', "field2", '/', "field3", '-+-+-+-', "field4" )
```

The label will look like this: `field1; field2/field3-+-+-+-field4`. Be sure to substitute

1. your actual field names instead of `"field1"`, etc.
2. the text or punctuation you want between the fields instead of `'; '` and `'/'` and `'-+-+-+-'`

Comment: I feel he wants to label **the cover layer** ("towns") with attributes coming from the point layer ("interest points") ... no ?

Comment: I wrote my answer before I realized the question isn't completely clear. Your interpretation seems equally possible. Hopefully the OP will clarify.

Answer (score 1):

you could to use one expresions for show only the labels that follow one expresion

in Labels Properties >> Rendering >> Show Labes >> Edit >> add the next expresion

"town name" = attribute( @atlas_feature, 'town name' )